# Plotting a function with discrete x values in gnuplot

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I need to plot a function `f(x)`, where `x` is discrete set of values (in my case positive integers). I couldn't find a way to specify a step-size when using the range option and samples doesn't seem to be the right solution. Finally, I would like to approximate `f(x)` with a smooth function.

Answer (score 8):

I don't quite understand why samples is not the solution to your problem.

If I want to plot sin(x) on an interval between 0 and 10 with a point at every integer I use

```
set xrange [0:10]
set sample 11
plot sin(x) w p
```

Obviously the number of samples is xmax-xmin+1 (10 - 0 + 1 = 11).

Finally to tackle the approximation problem have a look at [this website](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/misc2-e.html#9.3) which discusses linear least squares fitting. For simple linear interpolation use `lp` instead of `p`.

Comment: The `smooth` style doesn't work if you have a sample spec that is identical to the number of datapoints.

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively, play around with the `ceil(x)` or `floor(x)` functions.

Maybe have a look at this example:
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/prob2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
plot [1:12] '+' u ($0):(f($0))
```

Where, `$0` will be replaced by 1, 2, ..., 12. You can even do a smooth on this. For instance:

```
f(x)=sin(2*x)
plot [1:12] f(x) t 'the function'\
          , '+' u ($0):(f($0)) t 'the points'\
          , '+' u ($0):(f($0)) smooth cspline t 'the smooth'
```

Comment: Bit sketchy solution. `$0` are line numbers. `plot [52:127] "+" us 0:(f($0))` already breaks unless you increase the number of samples. I'd at least add the lower value of the range spec to `$0`.

Comment: Btw., gnuplot 5.1 now has not only individual sampling ranges (new in 5.0) for each part of a plot, but also individual sampling increments.